# SFTP nologin user public key auth will not work

Tags: sftp, key-authentication, nologin

Here is the user's configuraitons

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep sftp
sftpadmin:x:1001:1001::/backups:/sbin/nologin
```

Created directory structure

```
mkdir -p /backups/.ssh/
touch /backups/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown sftpadmin:sftpusers/backups/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 /backups/.ssh
sudo chown sftpadmin:sftpusers /backups/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 /backups/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I then added my clients public key to the authorized_keys file.

Then tried this

```
sftp -v -oPort=22 -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa sftpadmin@10.10.10.10
```

But I get prompted for a password every time.
Checking `/var/log/secure` shows no info unless I type the password.

I tried using the same RSA key pair with another user account that has a home directory, It works fine with SSH and SFTP public key auth.

But every time I try to connect via SFTP to `sftpadmin`, I get prompted for a password. The server refuses to use the public key. Why? How to fix this?

EDIT:

- Running centos 7.9.2009
- OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
- /etc/ssh/sshd_config setting `AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys`
- assigned user `/bin/bash` for shell restarted ssh, same problem
- selinux is disabled
- firewalld is disabled

**UPDATE:**
Got it working. IT was a combination of

- /etc/passwd configuration
- ChrootDirectory configuration /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- Permissions

I did the following to fix:

- Kept /etc/passwd the way it was stated above.
- Edited /etc/ssh/ssh_config configured the following

  ```
  Match Group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /backups/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ```
- Made sure the following was created and configured the proper way

  ```
  mkdir -p /backups/.ssh
  touch /backups/.ssh/authorized_keys
  chown root:sftpusers /backups
  chown -R sftpadmin:sftpusers /backups/.ssh
  chmod 755 /backups/
  chmod 600 -R /backups/.ssh
  ```

This combination worked. The problem was ownership of chroot jails. Needs to be owned by root, not any other user.

Comment: What Unix/Linux is this? What is the setting for AuthorizedKeysFile in the sshd_config? What happens if you change the home directory to /home/stfpadmin? If you allow the user a valid shell?

Comment: Updated with edit of what you asked. I tried moving the path to /home/sftpadmin, still does not work. Keep getting prompted for a password